# Gutenberg Blocks doesn't render correctly when using do_blocks

Tags: php, plugin-development, javascript, block-editor

I'm trying to render a `post_content` with blocks using the `do_blocks` function, that takes a gutenberg content, parses every block, and returns an HTML string.

The problem is that some blocks aren't rendering correctly. I suppose it is because `do_blocks` doesn't enqueue the blocks scripts, it only parses the  blocks.

For example, the `core-embed/youtube` instead of rendering the iframe of the YouTube video, only shows the video URL.

[image: bug example]

Blocks that renders using the a PHP `render_callback` function renders correctly, so its seems related to JS.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Is this still an issue?